# What is the probability to send a message successfully

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Suppose that there's a channel divided into slots (units of time). At each slot, stations may or may not send a message, as follows:
>
> 1. $n$ red stations: each one of them sends a message at every slot with probability $0.2$
> 2. "Many" green stations such that *the number* of stations transmitting a message at a given slot is a random variable Poisson distributed with $\lambda = 0.35$.
> 3. One yellow station which always send a message on even slots.
>
> What is the probability that exactly one station is sending a message on a random slot?

So I calculated the following probabilities:

1. Probability that only one green station was sending a message (among the greens): $\frac{0.35^1}{1!} \cdot e^{-0.35} = 0.2466$
2. Probability that no green station was sending a message: $e^{-0.35} = 0.7046$
3. Probability that only one red station was sending a message (among the reds):$n\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.8^{(n-1)}$
4. Probability that no red station was sending a message:
   $0.8^n$

Now, let's calculate the probability for a successful transmit on a slot (only one message was sent)

**Even slot:**

1. Successful yellow message: $0.8^n \times 0.7046$

**Odd slot:**

2. Successful green message: $0.2466 \times 0.8^n$
3. Successful red message: $n\cdot 0.2\cdot 0.8^{n-1}\times 0.7046$

Since slot is chosen uniformly at random the final probability is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[0.8^{n}\times0.7046\right]+\frac{1}{2}\left[0.2466\times0.8^{n}+n\cdot0.2\cdot0.8^{(n-1)}\times0.7046\right]$$

I'd like to get a proof verification.

I'm pretty sure of what I did (but at the same time feeling a bit insecure about it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that the red stations are a random variable $R$, green stations are a random variable $G$ and the yellow station a random variable $Y$ and independently distirbuted.

Each of these random variables are distributed accordingly as below

$R \text{~} Bin(n,0.2), k = 0,1,2,3,...$

$G \text{~} Poi (0.35), k = 0,1,2,3,..$

$Y \text{~} =1, k = 2,4,6,...$

$    =0, k = 1,3,5,...$

Define a new Variable $Z = R+G+Y$

All you have to do is find $P(Z =1)$.

I am working on the solution, but this is the best way to skin the cat, I believe.

**Here is the link that you can follow to get the joint pmf**

$P(Z = 1) = P(R=1,G=0, Y=0) + P(R=0, G=1, Y=0) + P(R=0,G=0, Y=1)$

Following your final result, you are capturing all the said events.  I am thinking that you are absolutely right.

[Sum of Binomial and Poisson](http://www.mathstatica.com/SumBinomialPoisson/)

Comment: You are welcome!!